# foreach statement (get string values)

Tags: c#, asp.net

Can someone please help me out?  My code for splitting the strings is working however, i still need to use the splitted string my page. How can i achieve this? Here's my current code

```
    private void SplitStrings()
    {
        List<string> listvalues = new List<string>();
        listvalues = (List<string>)Session["mylist"];
        string[] strvalues = listvalues.ToArray();

        if (listvalues != null)
        {
            foreach (string strElement in listvalues)
            { 
                string[] prods = strElement.ToString().Split("|".ToCharArray());
                string prodName = prods[0].ToString();
                Response.Write(prodName);
            }
        }
    }
```

[link text](http://i46.tinypic.com/11b18ol.jpg)

how can i replace the response.write with any label or literal? when i tried to use a literal on the code it displays one single string not all of the strings that's been splitted.

any ideas?

Comment: I'm not sure I can tell what problem you're seeing - can you explain in more detail what output you want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of just assigning the value use the concatenation operator to get all the strings. If your label name is label1 then something like

```
label1.Text += prods[0].ToString();
```

will be enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only seeing one `prodName` in the label then it sounds to me like you are doing something like this when assigning the value of the label:

`label1.text = prodName`

This will simply set the value of `label1` to `prodName`. In fact you need to contatenate the label and do something similar to this:

`label1.text += prodName`

This essentially says, take the value of `label1` and add `prodName` to the end. The first statement was saying take the value of `label1` and set it to `prodName`

Answer (score 0):

Just cycle over the string array:

```
foreach(string s in prods)
{
  response.write(s);
}
```

BTW this `strElement.ToString().Split("|".ToCharArray());`

can be replaced by this `strElement.Split('|');`

because strElement is already a string and to specify a char you have to use single quotes.